# jQuery nth-child nth-of-type Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to insert a clearfix div after x amount of elements so that I can get nicely formatted columns.

I've tried both `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` and I only get a single div added after the first x items.

```
$('#content .product-layout:nth-child(3)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>');
```

Creates a div after the third .product-layout div.

```
$('#product-row div:nth-child(3)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>');
```

Creates a div after the third .product-layout div.

I need to create the div after each 3rd existing product-layout div.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `n` to select every third child element with class `product-layout` of `#content`:

```
$('#content .product-layout:nth-child(3n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>');
// ----------------------------------  ^ here
```

Comment: Geez.  I saw it was 3n but then in the examples it was just the numeral without the n. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `3n` for a repeated element list, `:nth-child(3)` selects only 3rd child where as `:nth-child(3n)` will select 3, 6, 9... etc

```
$('#product-row div:nth-child(3n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ydhD2/)

- [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)