# nth-of-type not working javascript carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JS to create a carousel which displays 3 images, when pressing next/back one image is replaced by the next in the sequence. The first 3 load, because of the jquery bellow. when i press back (arrow on left) the next image loads however the other two disappear. Initially the next button dose not do anything until the back button is pressed.

I am dynamically loading the images from an API so i am using a class with nth-of-type to determine a chronological order of each image in the sequence.

```
  $('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
  });

  $('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':nth-of-type(1)');
    }
    next.children(':nth-of-type(1)').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
      next.next().children(':nth-of-type(1)').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).siblings(':nth-of-type(1)').children(':nth-of-type(1)').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });

  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.item:nth-of-type(1)').addClass('active');
     $('.item:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('active');
     $('.item:nth-of-type(3)').addClass('active');
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery nth-child nth-of-type Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553536/jquery-nth-child-nth-of-type-not-working)

Comment: `:nth-child` doesn't appear anywhere in your quoted code. `:nth-of-type` does (which is something else entirely), but not `:nth-child`.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing your HTML structure, but you probably need to look up what `:nth-of-type` means. `.item:nth-of-type` **doesn't** mean "the nth `.item`". It means "an element with class `item` that is also the nth element of its type (tagname) in its parent." You may want jQuery's `:eq(n)` extension, but again, we can't tell without a [mcve].

Comment: yea i meant nth-of-type

Comment: Why not use `$(this).siblings[0]`, or better `$(this).parent().children()[0]` (handles single item properly)? Needs wrapping in extra `$(...)` to get a jQuery object.

Comment: @franx thanks for the help.